# Image not reloading in my html

Tags: html, angular

I am building an angular app and in one of the components i am trying to load an image, but it is throwing a 404 not found. I guess I am not giving my path correctly. Could someone please help me with it ?
my screenshot for the component structure and html code with it
[image: Structure]

My html page with the error:

[image: html page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy your images into assets folder. Angular can only statics files like images from assets folder and then

```
<img src="assets\img\elliot.jpg">
```

Comment: where should my assets folder be ? 
in the root ?

Comment: its inside src/assets

Comment: @Sajeetharan You _can_ place your images anywhere, just make sure to declare them in the `assets` array in `.angular-cli.json`.